# Querying database takes too long

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, pyqt5

I'm using a PyQt5 built app to load and update an Azure database and when the queries are run the app freezes. This takes a while especially when updating the application with multiple entries or calling stored procedures.

So I started looking into multi threading as a means to speed things up but nothing I tried worked and things ended up messy.

How could I make the querying, loading and updating as quick as possible through multithreading?

Or is there another way?

My connection block:

```
# importing required libraries

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidgetItem,QWidget,QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import ProgrammingError, InterfaceError, OperationalError
from mysql.connector.locales.eng import client_error



from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


import datetime

import threading







# main window class
     
class MainScreen(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        #importing the layout file
        
        loadUi("layout.ui",self)

        self.setWindowTitle("PNG")
        
        
        self.col_names = ['S/N',
    'Name',
    'Date',
    'Quantity',
    'Comments']
        
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.col_names)
        self.header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        self.tableWidget.blockSignals(True)
        
        
        #load and update table function
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.load_table)
        
        
        
        # connecting to the database
        
        global mydb
        
        try:
            
            
            
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="##########.mysql.database.azure.com",
                             user='#########'+'@######-mysql',
                             password='password',
                             database="database1",
                             connection_timeout=1800,
                             ssl_ca='DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem')
            
            
    



    
    def load_table(self):
        
        
        self.worker = WorkerThread()
        
        self.worker.start()
        
        self.worker.query_result.connect(self.populate_table)
     
        
     
        
     def populate_table(self, val):
         
         
        
     
        self.tableWidget.blockSignals(True)
        
                
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
 
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(val):
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
 
                for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                    if data == None:
                        data = ""
                        self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number,
                        column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
                    else:
                        
                        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data))
                        item.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(128, 128, 128)))
                        item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ Qt.ItemIsEditable)
                        self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, item)
                        
                        
        
        self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
        
        
        
    


        self.tableWidget.blockSignals(False)
    
    
    
    
   
    

class WorkerThread(QThread):
    
    def run(self):
        
        try:
                
                mycursor = mydb.cursor()
                
                
                mycursor.callproc('database1.load_names')
            
        
                for r in mycursor.stored_results():
                
                    result = r.fetchall()
                    
                    
        
        except OperationalError:
            Msgbox = QMessageBox()
            Msgbox.setText("Error! Connection to database lost!")
            Msgbox.exec()
        
        
        except NameError:
            Msgbox = QMessageBox()
            Msgbox.setText("Error! Connect to database!")
            Msgbox.exec()
        
        
        query_result = pyqtSignal(list)
        
        
        self.query_result.emit(result)
        
        



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainScreen()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

layout.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget"/>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Load Data</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Update Data</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: First of all, don't insert rows one by one: set the row count based on your needs, and then set the items. Then, have you considered using the QtSql module? QTableWidgets are high level interfaces, they are usually not intended to be used with database models (which can be very big and require fast model interaction). Note: threading is **not** an option, as widgets are not thread safe.

Comment: I'll check out the QtSql module; does it make database loading and querying faster? Also, on the threading issue, is there a work around?

Comment: The QtSql module can directly create models that interact with the database very fast (they work on the C++ level), so if you only need to do simple select queries and updates, it will be much faster and reliable even with very big models. I never used it with Azure so I don't know how well it works, but it generally works fine with all basic sql implementations as long as they are standard. The only way of using threads and interact with the main thread is through signals, but since the model should still be in the main thread (it's directly linked to the view), that wouldn't change much.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the recommendations. I'll give QtSql a try.

Comment: Okay, so how about instead of using multi threading to speed up database querying I simply use it so while the database is being queried the app doesn't freeze. How would I go about that?

Comment: If the problem is that the connection is slow, then I'm afraid that QtSql might not be the solution (sql connections can only be used in the thread they are created). You could create a QThread that makes the connection and queries the remote db, and then emit the results to update the actual model. As written above, you shouldn't add items individually, and you might consider subclassing your own model.

Comment: Hi, so I created a QThread and a Worker class as well an emit signal to enable the application stay responsive while data is being pulled from the database, as well as when computations are taking place. But when I run it it gives me a 'Python has stopped running' message. I've edited my question to show the changes made to my script. If you could point me to where I went astray that would be immense. Thanks.

Comment: Signals must be created at class level. And it crashes because you created `query_result` as local variable, but then you try to access it like it was an instance member. Also, run your code in a terminal or prompt to see the full traceback of errors, if your IDE doesn't provide useful output.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was able to connect the slots and signals and get it to work. I have a question though - if I wanted to add the block of code which populates the table widget to the worker class how would I do that because sometimes the data loaded can be quite large? It's giving me some issues because the ui objects aren't in the worker class and I can't figure out how to call it.

Comment: I'd like to call the table widgets and ui widgets from the worker class.

Comment: Widgets are not thread safe, you cannot create them (or their elements) in external threads.

Comment: Oh! I think I understand now. Thanks for the help, it's been really useful.

Comment: Hi, so, it turns out that despite the function running the multi threading isn't actually working because the application still becomes unresponsive when running anything inside the WorkerThread class. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing in the thread, so I cannot answer. You're not trying to create QTableWidgetItems there, are you?

Comment: No, I just want to be able to run functions in the WorkerThread class that uses multi theading so the GUI isn't unresponsive when these functions are running. Right now the functions in the class run but the GUI is still unresponsive even though I called the QThread module in the class and imported it.

Comment: What is actually running in the function doesn't matter much to me, I just want to make sure the multi threading works.